# Morava's "Motives and cell bundles"? 

Tags: motives, at.algebraic-topology, big-picture

Hello, do you know more about, or some exposition of [Morava's talk](https://www.ams.org/amsmtgs/2110_abstracts/1046-55-2092.pdf)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google knows about this preprint ("A theory of base motives") which seems related:

http://folk.uio.no/rognes/yff/morava.pdf